# Is there a standard equation of form $y=f(x)$ i.e. explicit function representing below given input output pair?

Tags: functions

```
X   Y
-------
1   1
2   1
3   3
4   1
5   3
6   5
7   7
8   1
9   3
10  5
11  7
12  9
13  11
14  13
15  15
16  1
17  3
18  5
19  7
20  9
21  11
22  13
23  15
24  17
25  19
26  21
27  23
28  25
29  27
30  29
31  31
32  1
33  3
34  5
```

I tried representing the pattern in form of line graph.

The pattern is like this,

If $n$ is of the form $2^{N}$ then $f(n) = 1$ else $f(n) = f(n-1)+2$

Also, use $f(1) = 1$ as base condition (already covered by above logic).

Comment: It's quite rare that "n is of the form 2^n".

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to construct a simple description. The first clever thing to notice is: Every number $n \in \mathbb N$ can be written in the form $n = 2^m + k$ for some unique numbers $m\in \mathbb N$ and $k \in \{0,\dots,2^m - 1\}$. The reason we describe $n$ in this way is because in this representation, the function you are looking for is simply
$$f(2^m + k) = 2k + 1.$$

Why is this true? Well, intuitively, the function you are looking for is just always looking for the next power of two, and when it finds it, it resets to $1$, and then keeps on adding 2 to the previous value. So $2^m$ gives 1, $2^m + 1$ gives $3$, $2^m + 2$ gives $5$, and in general $2^m + k$ gives $2k + 1$. You can also directly check that this function fulfils your recursion!

Now we just need to find a simple way to get the numbers $m$ and $k$ belonging to $n$. For $m$, the binary logarithm is built for this, since $n = 2^{\log_2 n}$. So take this binary logarithm and round it down: $m := \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor$. Then $2^m$ is the largest power of two which is smaller than $n$. And $k$ is then the difference between $n$ and that:

$$n = \underbrace{2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}}_{= 2^m} + \underbrace{n - 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}}_{= k}.$$

So now we have our $k$, and the solution to the original question is:

$$f(n) = 2 (n - 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}) + 1 = 2n - 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor + 1} + 1.$$